# Android : How to change color of two different lines in the same Button?

Tags: android

I'm recently trying to build a UI for my friend's app.
I got some problem and have no idea how to deal with.
I've searched solutions for a while. 
But still can't deal with my problem.

[Here's what my apps looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyU6z.png)

I want to know if there's a way to change the color of the two text in the middle button column.
What I want to looks like is : number is pink, and the Chinese is gray, and two different sizes.

Comment: You can post your xml to point on your issue...

Comment: Change `Button` and use `LinearLayout` with two `TextViews` where you can custom text as you need.

Answer (score 2):

Best option would be to separate both texts into two TextViews as Safa suggested in the comment and Elvira Parpalac answered.

If you really want to keep both texts in one button, you can use [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) with [ForegroundColorSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html)

```
String text1 = "xyz";
String text2 = "abc";
SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(text1 + "\n" + text2);
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, text1.length(), 0);
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), text1.length(), spannable.length(), 0);

button.setText(spannable);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make custom buttons using LinearLayout. You need just to set `android:clickable="true"` property to LinearLayout. Here is an example for your case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/buttonList"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:baselineAligned="false"
   android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="22"
        android:textColor="@color/bp_disabled_day" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="A"
        android:textColor="@color/ampm_text_color" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="22"
        android:textColor="@color/bp_disabled_day" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="B"
        android:textColor="@color/ampm_text_color" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="22"
        android:textColor="@color/bp_disabled_day" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="C"
        android:textColor="@color/ampm_text_color" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, you need to add this file `drawable/button_selector.xml`. In this file you will write styles for "button" (when it is in different states).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime">
<item android:drawable="@color/bpWhite" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" />
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

And the last step is to set OnclickListener in your code:

```
 LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.layout1);
 layout1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        //TODO: Write your code
     }
 });
```

The result:

[image]

[image]